# ¿Como obtener el valor de un AsyncTask? Esperar hasta obtener el resultado

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

primero que todo, soy un tanto inexperto (muy inexperto) con el `AsyncTask` y tengo dos problemas.

primero le paso un user y pass al Task para comparar los con los de mi DB en la seccion Login y el segundo es lo mismo pero necesito llenar un Spinner con la respuesta en la seccion SpinnerQ.

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask <String,String,String> {

    AlertDialog AD;
    Context context;
    MyTask (Context ctx){
        context =ctx;
    }
    boolean  validacion;
    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String type = params[0];



        if(type=="spinnerq"){
            String registro_url = "http://10.0.2.2/spinner2.php";
            String dataParsed, singleParsed;
            String json = "";
            String result = "";
            try {

                URL url = new URL(registro_url);
                HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                http.setRequestMethod("POST");

                http.setDoInput(true);
                InputStream IS =http.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(IS,"iso-8859-1"));
                String Line;
                while((Line=BR.readLine())!=null){

                    json +=Line;

                }
                BR.close();
                IS.close();
                http.disconnect();
                result=json.toString();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result; }
        return null;    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       AD = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        AD.setTitle("Login Status");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result) {
       AD.setMessage(result);
       AD.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    }
}
```

esto me trae un este Json que se puede ver en un alert dialog

> {"Pregunta":"Tangananica o Tanganana?"}{"Pregunta":"Que le pasa a
>   Lupita?"}{"Pregunta":"que sera lo que quiere el negro?"}

El problema es que no puedo pasarlo a mi activity y ponerlo en el spinner.

```
public class Seleccionpregunta extends AppCompatActivity {

static Spinner sp;
static TextView tv;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_seleccionpregunta);
    sp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.questionSpinner);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    MyTask BW = new MyTask(this);
    String type = "spinnerq";
    BW.execute(type);



}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

agradecería mucho si pueden ayudarme!

Comment: Has trabajado con adaptadores antes?

Comment: [Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info): Utilizar esta etiqueta solo si la pregunta está asociada al uso, funcionalidades o problemas con el IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes realizarlo de esta manera mediante el método [**get()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()), para obtener el valor obtenido en `onPostExecute()`:

```
  String resultadoAsynctask =  new MyAsyncTask().execute().get();
```

Debes tomar en cuenta que el proceso esperara hasta obtener el resultado del AsyncTask, esto por el uso de [**get()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()):

> [**get()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()) Espera si es necesario para que se complete el cálculo,
>   y luego recupera su resultado.

En tu código sería:

```
 try {

        String type = "spinnerq";
        String resultadoAsynctask =  new MyTask().execute(type).get();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, resultó perfecto
estuve mucho tiempo tratando de hacer esto.

Comment: Excelente @Sodro, un placer ayudarte amigo.