# Esperar que termine un proceso asincrónico en Android

Tags: java, android, asincronismo

Estoy trabajando en *AndroidStudio*, programando en *Java* donde se tiene una función que hace `Post` de datos a una *URL* que tengo, y se suben unas imágenes, junto a otros datos.

Este proceso está perfecto, pero el problema es que como el proceso es asincrónico, se termina después de verificar si se suben todas las imágenes.

Lo que tengo es el siguiente código:

```
boolean ImgSubidasOK = true;
...
btnSubirFotosSistema.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ...
        SubeFotografia(parametro1, parametro2);
        if (ImgSubidasOK){
            //hacerAlgo, ACTIVIDAD 1
        }
        else {
            //hacerAlgo, ACTIVIDAD 2
        }
        ...
    }
}
...
public void SubeFotografia(final String parametro1, final String parametro2) {
    ...
    PostResponseAsyncTask task = new PostResponseAsyncTask(
        MainActivity.this, postData, new AsyncResponse() {
        @Override
            public void processFinish(String s) {
                if (s.contains("uploaded_success")){
                    //Subida exitosa imagen
                }
                else {
                    ImgSubidasOK = false;
                    //Error subida foto
                }
            }
        }
    );
    String URLFinal = "https://URLASUBIRIMAGENES.php";
    task.execute(URLFinal);
    ...
}
```

Entonces me gustaría que luego de ejecutar `SubeFotografia(parametro1, parametro2);` ya tenga el resultado final de `processFinish`.

Porque se me ha dado el caso que hay error de subida de datos y se va directo a **`if(ImgSubidasOK)`** y hace *ACTIVIDAD 1* como si todo hubiera estado bien, pero en realidad tiene que entrar el **`else`** y hacer *ACTIVIDAD 2*.

Esto debido a que entra primero al `if` haciendo *ACTIVIDAD 1* (porque está ese valor en `true`) y luego ocurre un error de subida de foto en el **`processFinish`** cambiándose el valor de **`ImgSubidasOK`** a `false`, pero ya es muy tarde para verificar.

Además necesito que termine primero la función **`SubeFotografia`**, junto con su proceso asincrónico, y **después** poder continuar con el código que sigue (las verificaciones de `if`, `else` y `ImgSubidasOK`).

El código lo simplifiqué para mostrarlo acá, pero tiene mas detalles que no vienen al caso.

Comment: Tienes que organizar la idea de tu problema. Personalmente se me hace dificil entenderte. Lo que quieres es saber si el `PostResponseAsyncTask` termino?

Comment: Si disculpa fue un poco enredado.
No, mira, si se cuando termina el PostResponseAsyncTask, lo que quiero saber es como hacer que ese Task termine primero dentro de la funcion, esperando de alguna forma para que se complete la funcion llamada SubeFotografia y asi poder seguir con el resto del codigo

Comment: debes organizar bien la estructura de un asynctask ...

Comment: @Pato es importante realices el [tour] y leas [ask] para formular correctamente una pregunta, es un poco complicado entender lo que deseas.

Comment: Es importante también que revises en el sitio, lo que preguntas ya se realizó:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/124662/como-obtener-el-valor-de-un-asynctask saludos.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes asumir que el valor de `ImgSubidasOK` vaya a cambiar cuando tú esperas su lectura ya que estás trabajando con datos asíncronos. Te recomendaría cambiar tu código, algo asi:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse
btnSubirFotosSistema.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ...
        SubeFotografia(parametro1, parametro2, this);

    @Override
    public void processFinish(String output) {
        if (s.contains("uploaded_success")){
            //Subida exitosa imagen, hacer algo Actividad 1
        }
        else {
            //ImgSubidasOK = false; //comentado
            //Error subida foto, actividad 2 hacer algo
        }
    }
    ....
    public void SubeFotografia(final String parametro1, final String parametro2, AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
        PostResponseAsyncTask task = new PostResponseAsyncTask(MainActivity.this, postData, asyncResponse);
```

Así, la respuesta la manejas en el *Activity* hasta que la petición realmente haya terminado (bien o mal) y no dependes de la lectura de un *flag*.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné.

Cambiando esta linea:

```
task.execute(URLFinal);
```

Por esta:

```
String str_result = task.execute(URLFinal).get();
```

Comment: Si tu respuesta es la correcta, puedes marcarla como aceptada. Además estaría bueno explicar por qué hiciste ese cambio, [editando la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/136592/edit).