# urlconnection error en Android : NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, http-post

Estoy intentado utilizar url connection en mi app android y me da el siguiente error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                                        at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1128)
>                                                                        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
>                                                                        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
>                                                                        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
>                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:70)
>                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:50)
>                                                                        at
>   libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
>                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
>                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
>                                                                        at
>   libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
>                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
>                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
>                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
>                                                                        at
>   libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
>                                                                        at Nuevo6.makeRequest(Nuevo6.java:86)
>                                                                        at Nuevo6$1.onClick(Nuevo6.java:64)
>                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4421)
>                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18190)
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
>                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

os dejo el código del onCreate()

```
ImageView siguiente = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.i("Vehiculos",vehiculos.getText().toString());

                miCC.setVehiclos(vehiculos.getText().toString());
                miCC.setAparcamiento(apar.getText().toString());
                miCC.setInfo(notas.getText().toString());

                Gson gson = new Gson();
                json = gson.toJson(miCC);

                Log.i("JSON",json);

                String result = makeRequest("urlWebService",json);

                Intent passIntent = new Intent();
                passIntent.setClass(Nuevo6.this,Menu.class);
                startActivity(passIntent);
            }
        });
```

Según veo en el log la codificación del JSON es correcta y la url del webService funciona bien pues si la meto en el navegador me isnerta en la BBDD un nuevo registro con los datos vacíos.

Y por último os dejo la funcion makeRequest que es la que da el problema en la sentencia: `" urlConnection.connect();"`

```
 public static String makeRequest(String uri, String json) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        String url;
        String data = json;
        String result = null;
        try
        {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(uri).openConnection()));
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.connect();

            OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(data);
            writer.close();
            outputStream.close();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            String line = null; StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); }
        return result;
    }
```

Creo que mi error debe estar un poco más arriba en la sentencia  `urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(uri).openConnection()));` ya que no estoy utilizando la variable string url, sino que he metido como uri la url (https://direcionDeMiWebService.php) y no sé si hay que hacer un casting o qué, creo que uri y url no es lo mismo y lo estoy pasando mal a la función.

Muchas gracias, un saludo

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a tu LogCat el problema es **NetworkOnMainThreadException**

> **NetworkOnMainThreadException**: se provoca cuando tratas de realizar
>   operaciones en el hilo principal (Main thread), lo cual es incorrecto.

[Error android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException en usar HttpURLConnection de Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13521/error-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-en-usar-httpurlconnection-de-andro/13549#13549)

Para solucionar esto como opción realiza  tu petición dentro de un [**Asynctask**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask).

[¿Como obtener el valor de un AsyncTask? Esperar hasta obtener el resultado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/124662/como-obtener-el-valor-de-un-asynctask-esperar-hasta-obtener-el-resultado)

```
public class RequestTask extends AsyncTask <String,String,String> {

    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String uri= params[0];
        String json = params[1];
        /*--------------------------------------------*/
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        String url;
        String data = json;
        String result = null;
        try
        {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(uri).openConnection()));
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.connect();

            OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(data);
            writer.close();
            outputStream.close();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            String line = null; StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); }
        return result;
        /*--------------------------------------------*/

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //result retorna valor obtenido por la petición.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    }
}
```

para obtener el resultado de la petición se debe realizar de esta forma:

```
  //String result = makeRequest("urlWebService",json);
  String resultadoPeticion =  new RequestTask().execute(new String[]{"urlWebService",json}).get();
```

---

P.D. **No uses esto en una aplicación de producción**:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy =
                    new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

lo que realiza es desactivar la politica de no permitir operaciones en el hilo principal.

Answer (score 0):

Eran dos problemas, por un lado que estaba poniendo un String en vez de una variable URL y por otro he tenido que añadir la sentencia :

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy =
                    new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
```

Os dejo como queda la función makeRequest por si la podéis/queréis reutilizar:

```
public static String makeRequest(String json) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        URL url;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy =
                    new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        try {
            url = new URL("http://www.miWebService.php");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        String data = json;
        String result = null;
        try
        {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.connect();

            OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(data);
            writer.close();
            outputStream.close();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            String line = null; StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); }
        return result;
    }
```

Ya si queréis ser un poco más "PRO" meterlo en un AsyncTask para que en caso de fallar no se bloquee el hilo principal y podéis mostrar un Toast de que falló la comunicación con el servidor!!!

Comment: **No es opción desactivar la política para permitir operaciones en el hilo principal**, te recomiendo evitar usar esto :  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy =
                    new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy). =-( Usa un Asynctask.

Comment: gracias @Jorgesys, sin esa sentencia no me da error, no he tenido otra posibilidad

Comment: Como habías comentado usando un Asynctask @midlab revisa el que agregué en mi respuesta,.