# Filtro en SearchView android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Tengo un recyclerview que carga datos de una clase modelo, y al implementar un filtro no hace nada.
Los datos los descargo desde una web con volley y las guardo en una bd sqlite (todo esto desde un Fragment).
Aqui mi codigo:

Fragment

```html
public class InicioFragment extends Fragment implements Response.Listener<JSONArray>,Response.ErrorListener, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

    ArrayList<MyModel> lista;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Activity activity;
    IFragments interface_frag;
    DataAdapter dataAdapter;
    
        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);
        lista=new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView= (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_m);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        con = new conexion(getContext());
        request = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        new cargar_data().execute();

        dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(lista, getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        mostrar_lista();
        return rootView;
    }

    private void mostrar_lista() {
        try {
            int id = getFromSharedPref("Id");
            bd = con.getReadableDatabase();
            String[] par = {String.valueOf(id)};
            String[] campos = {TablaUser.Id, TablaUser.Tipo, TablaUser.IdRegion};

            Cursor cursor = bd.query(TablaUser.TablaUser, campos, TablaUser.Id + "=?", par, null, null, null);

            int id  = 0;
            String tipo = "";
            int idregion = 0;

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                id = cursor.getInt(0);
                tipo = cursor.getString(1);
                idregion = cursor.getInt(2);

                String url = "http://www.xxx.mx/yyy/zzz.svc/GetAll/" + id + "/" + tipo + "/" + idregion + "";
                url = url.replace(" ", "%20");

                jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, this, this);
                jsonArrayRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(MY_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
                request.add(jsonArrayRequest);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se encontraron datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            cursor.close();
            bd.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private int getFromSharedPref(String id) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Login_pref", getContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getInt(id, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ERROR " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println();
        Log.d("ERROR ", error.toString());        
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        MyModel model = null;

        if (response != null) {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                    int Id = jsonObject.optInt("Id");
                    String Nombre = jsonObject.optString("Nombre");
                    String Fecha = jsonObject.optString("Fecha");
                    ...etc

                    model = new ProdMuestreo(Id, etc);

                    bd = con.getReadableDatabase();
                    String[] par = {String.valueOf(Id)};
                    String[] campos = {_mymodel.id};
                      Cursor cursor = bd.query(_mymodel.TDatos, campos, _mymodel.Id + "=?", par, null, null, null);

                    if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        bd.close();
                        bd = con.getWritableDatabase();
                        con.insert(Id,etc);
                        bd.close();
                    }

                    cursor.close();
                    bd.close();

                    lista.add(muestreos);
                }
                DataAdapter dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(lista);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
                
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se encontraron datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
 @Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
    return false;
}

}
```

Adapter

```html
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.DataHolder> implements View.OnClickListener, Filterable
{
    private View.OnClickListener listener;
    ArrayList<MyModel> list;
    ArrayList<MyModel> listAll;
    IFragments interface_frag;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Context context;

    public DataAdapter(ArrayList<MyModel> list, Context context)
    {
        this.list=list;
        this.listAll=new ArrayList<>(list);
        this.context = context;      
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DataHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items_inicio,null,false);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams layParams = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        view.setLayoutParams(layParams);

        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        return new DataHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DataHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.nom.setText("Nombre: "+lista.get(position).getNombre().toString());
        holder.solic.setText("Solicita: "+ lista.get(position).getSolicitante().toString());
        holder.fecha.setText("Fecha: "+ lista.get(position).getFecha());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (list != null)
        {
            return list.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void setOnClickListener (View.OnClickListener listener){
        this.listener=listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(listener!=null){
            listener.onClick(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
             
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                ArrayList<MyModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                if (constraint.toString().isEmpty()) {
                    filteredList.addAll(listMuestreosAll);
                } else {
                    for (MyModel m : listMuestreosAll) {
                        if (m.getNombre().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                            filteredList.add(m);
                        }
                    }
                }
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = filteredList;
                return filterResults;
            }

             
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults filterResults) {
                list.clear();
                list.addAll((Collection<? extends MyModel>) filterResults.values);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    public class DataHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView text_ing,txt_cod,txt_fecha;

        public DataHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nom=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
            solic=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.solic);
            fecha=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fecha);

          }
    }
```

Mi clase modelo

```html
public class MyModel implements Serializable {
    private int Id;
    public String Nombre;
    private String Solicitante;
    private String Fecha;
   

    public MyModel(int id, String Nombre, String Solicitante, String Fecha)
    {   Id = id;
        Nombre = Nombre;
        Solicitante = Solicitante;
        Fecha = Fecha;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String Nombre) {
        Nombre = Nombre;
    }

     public String getSolicitante() {
        return Solicitante;
    }

    public void setSolicitante(String Solicitante) {
        Solicitante = Solicitante;
    }
    
      public String getFecha() {
        return Fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(String Fecha) {
        Fecha = Fecha;
    }
}
```

Comment: no hace nada pero revisaste el LogCat que mensajes registra?

Comment: @Jorgesys errores no muestra solo no entra a for (MyModel m : listaAll) y si hay datos

Comment: a que te refieres con clase modelo?

Comment: y no veo donde implementas el `getFilter()`

Comment: @junior la clase getfilteresta en el adapter, enseguida agrego la clase modelo

Comment: `getFilter()` en la clase adapter es la declaracion del metodo no veo es la implementacion o invocacion

Comment: en el metodo onQueryTextChange en el fragment @junior

Comment: @Huntzberger sabes que me parece que te esta faltando asignar los los metodos a volley

Comment: porque los declaras pero no veo donde se los pasas a volley

Comment: @junior hola ya lo añadi

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106801/discussion-between-junior-and-huntzberger).

Answer (score 1):

Tu método `showSelectedFragment()` es el que carga el **Fragment** que realiza la petición y llena el **Adapter**, pero en este caso estás inicializando el **Adapter** con una lista vacía, elimina las 2 líneas que realizan esto:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    DataAdapter dataAdapter;
    List<MyModel> lista;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        showSelectedFragment(new Inicio());

        //* Incorrecto. lista = new ArrayList<>();
        //* Incorrecto. dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(lista);
        ...
        ...
```

Otro detalle que tienes es que tu `Fragment` como comentaba es el que realiza la obtención de la información, pero este esta definiendo un `Adapter` a partir de una lista que es obtenida mediante un proceso asíncrono cargar_data(), puedo sugerirte realizar lo siguiente:

[¿Como obtener el valor de un AsyncTask? Esperar hasta obtener el resultado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/124662/como-obtener-el-valor-de-un-asynctask-esperar-hasta-obtener-el-resultado)

por lo tanto realiza el siguiente cambio

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);
    lista=new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView= (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_m);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    con = new conexion(getContext());
    request = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

    // new cargar_data().execute();
    new cargar_data().execute().get(); //* Espera a cargar los datos.

    dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(lista, getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    mostrar_lista();
    return rootView;
}
```

De esta forma se aseguraría obtener los datos y al terminar llenaría tu adapter.

Comment: Hola ya los borre ahora me lanza este error:  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.Filter ....adapter.DataAdapter.getFilter()' on a null object reference

Comment: @Huntzberger revisa el cambio que sugiero, lo que sucede es que si cargar_data() es un Asynctask, el proceso para obtener los datos es asincrono por lo que puede no obtenerlos si no espera hasta su obtención usando .get(), comenta los resultados, y revisa si tu Asynctas obtiene los datos y no tiene algún tipo de problema que se presente en el LogCat

Comment: ya hice el cambio que me sugiere pero queda igual, no pasa nada, todo lo hago en el fragment no en el mainactivity

Answer (score 0):

creo que lo mejor es declarar el `SearchView` como variable global consume un poco de memoria no se exactamente cuanto pero a veces hay que sacrificarla

**MainActivity**

```
SearchView searchView=null;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_search,menu);
    MenuItem item=menu.findItem(R.id.action.search);
    searchView=(SearchView) item.getActionView();
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**Fragment**

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    MainActivity self=((MainActivity) getActivity())
    self.searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this)
}
```

listo me cuentas si te sirvio

Comment: El problema en realidad es que no se llena el adapter con los datos que debería obtener mediante el Asynctask.

Comment: @Jorgesys yo ya hable con el y me dijo que el volley si le llenaba correctamente el recycler el problema era que no le funcionaba el filtro

Comment: y lo hace con un SearchView