# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que mi app realentice un dispositivo? ¿Usando los métodos onPause, onResume y onDestroy?

Tags: android, activity

Me he percatado que de las 3 apps que he hecho para android, las 3 presentan este mismo problema. El problema es que algunas veces hace que el dispositivo (celular / smartphone) ande lento o hace que salte una notificación diciendo que tal app está gastando la batería del dispositivo.

Ahora bien, leí un poco en la documentación de Android pero aún no llego a comprender del todo. Pongo de ejemplo los anuncios que uso de Google para monetizar mi app. Dicha implementación me dice que utilice los metodos 'pause' 'resume' y 'destroy' de su clase.

```
anuncio.pause();
anuncio.resume();
anuncio.destroy();
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿tengo que hacer lo mismo con todos los elementos de mi app? ¿Es decir que tengo que poner todos los TextView, ImageView, botones, variables string y demás en los métodos onPause, onResume y onDestroy?

Lo que busco es optimizar mis app y evitar que utilicen recursos cuando no lo necesitan.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Los anuncios pueden ocasionar se ralentize tu app cuando se realiza la carga, para esto puedes puedes hacer uso de un Handler.

por ejemplo realiza la carga de esta forma despuès de 1 segundo.

```
new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
@Override
public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
  if (!isBeingDestroyed) {
      final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
      final AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
      adView.loadAd(adRequest);
  }
}).sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 1000); // 1 segundo
```

Revisa esta respuesta:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446231/admob-banners-cause-high-cpu-usage

Aunque generalmente **la razòn por la cual se ralentizan las aplicaciones esta relacionada principalmente a la ejecuciòn de tareas o procesos en el hilo principal (UI Thread) lo cual debemos evitar.**

Cuando un proceso está bloqueado, el sistema operativo no puede llamar a onDraw(), lo que hace que la aplicaciòn se ralentize o se congele lo cual conduce a un mensaje ANR indicando que la aplicacion no responde. Para una mejor experiencia de usuario, se deben ejecutar ejecutemos estos procesos en un hilo secundario.

Para evitar operaciones en el hilo de la interfaz de usuario (UI Thread) podemos hacer uso de:

[**Asynctask**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)

y si desarrollas en Kotlin

**[Corrutinas](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines)**

Usando [**Asynctask**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) o **[Corrutinas](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines)** puedes realizar uno o varios procesos fuera del thread principal y esperar a un resultado.

Este es un ejemplo de como realizar una petición dentro de un [**Asynctask**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask).

[¿Como obtener el valor de un AsyncTask? Esperar hasta obtener el resultado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/124662/como-obtener-el-valor-de-un-asynctask-esperar-hasta-obtener-el-resultado)

```
public class RequestTask extends AsyncTask <String,String,String> {

    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String uri= params[0];
        String json = params[1];
        /*--------------------------------------------*/
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        String url;
        String data = json;
        String result = null;
        try
        {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(uri).openConnection()));
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.connect();

            OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(data);
            writer.close();
            outputStream.close();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            String line = null; StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); }
        return result;
        /*--------------------------------------------*/

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //result retorna valor obtenido por la petición.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    }
}
```

para obtener el resultado de la petición se debe realizar de esta forma:

```
  String resultadoPeticion =  new RequestTask().execute(new String[]{"urlWebService",json}).get();
```

---

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. Lo que entiendo es que es mejor que en cada uno de mis activities ponga un Handler para los anuncios (lo que hace que se carguen 1 segundo más tarde), es así? Y lo otro es que desconozco bastante de android, pero me dices que es mejor que haga una suma (Ej: 1+1) en un hilo secundario, es correcto? Porque muchos de los procesos de mis apps son tan sencillas como una suma o una resta simple.

Comment: Pude probar el Handler, pero al parecer mi problema yace en las imágenes que utilizo, hace que la aplicación demoré en estar lista, y obviamente hace trabajar más de lo debido al dispositivo.